# List of geometric theorems linked by two squares

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, big-list

I'm trying to create a classification for geometric theorems that relate to two squares As a type of organization and classification And the curiosity to explore

I have collected some theorems of this type that I will put in an answer/answers.

I hope you can help me expand my list.

It's important to note that I'm not looking for theorems about squares because it would become too extensive a list, I'm looking for theorems about a number of squares equal to exactly twoTherefore, theorems such as Van Opel's theorem are not accepted in the answers

Answer (score 15):

For now, I will only post pictures of the theorems. Perhaps later I will add links that talk about the theorems in detail

Potema's theorem:
[image]
Two squares created on the sides of a triangle $∆ABC$ And we set the point $M$ Which represents the middle $EF$ It will be constant no matter how you move point $C$ As long as $A,B$ are constant

Fensler-Hadwiger theorem
[image]
We have two squares with a common vertex between them, so they will be the midpoints of the spaces between the opposite vertices, and the centers of the two squares will form the vertices of a third square

[image]
Two squares with a common vertex, the previous three properties will be fulfilled

[image]
If two squares have a common vertex, the two red lines will be perpendicular and equal

[image]
If we have two identical squares with one vertex at the center of the other, the common area between the two squares will be equal to a quarter of the area of ​​one square

[image]
In the previous figure there are two properties achieved:
The first is that $AM=BM$
The second characteristic is that $PQ=2MN$

[image]
Two identical or different squares intersect and are enclosed between them $A,B,C,D$ The aforementioned equality will be achieved

[image]
If two identical or different squares have a common vertex, the blue area will be equal to the red area

[image]
If two squares have a common vertex, these three lines will meet at one point
[image]
Moreover, the circles of the two squares pass through the same point, which represents the center of the spiral similarity

[image]
If two squares have parallel sides, these lines will meet at one point
[image]
Furthermore itIf the two squares do not have parallel sides, then these lines will meet at one point.
[image]
In the previous figure it would be: $\frac{b}{a}=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}=Φ$

[image]
In the previous picture it is:
$X=\frac{5(A-B)}{8}$

[image]
We have two squares that have a common vertex, the point $F$ moves freely along the straight line $CD$ It will be points $A,C,Q$ Located on one straight line

[image]
Two squares in the plane In the general case, these two lines will be perpendicular

Here are some theorems that can be understood from pictures only without words:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @DS There is proof in one of the comments on this post: https://www.facebook.com/share/p/TkbGMp1ZfLeodWjB/?mibextid=TrneLp

Comment: nice explanation   .....         +1

Answer (score 4):

Euclid  [Book II Prop 6](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookII/propII6.html)  on what we would now describe algebraically as the difference of squares:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here are somewhat-natural generalizations of a couple of the two-squares-joined-at-a-vertex results from [OP's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4886056/409).

---

- Potema's Theorem

[image]

Let squares $\square A'B'C'D'$ and $\square A''B''C''D''$ be as shown, with $X$ the midpoint of $X'X''$.

If segment $A'A''$ remains fixed, and segment $D'D''$ keeps a constant length and inclination (in Potema's theorem, $D'=D''$), then midpoint $B$ remains fixed. Moreover, the position of $C$ relative to $D$ matches that of $B$ relative to $A$.

That is, $\square ABCD$ is a parallelogram, with $|AB|$ and $|CD|$ determined by the lengths and relative inclinations of $A'A''$ and $C'C''$.

Specifically, segments $AB$ and $CD$ form congruent triangles with segments of length $|AA'|$ and $|DD'|$ (more-specifically, segments perpendicular to $A'A''$ and $B'B''$). Likewise, segments $BC$ and $AD$ form congruent triangles with segments of length $|BB'|$ and $|CC'|$.

---

- Fensler-Hadwiger

Again, we have squares $\square A'B'C'D'$ and $\square A''B''C''D''$, and midpoints $X$ of $X'X''$.

[image]

The square with opposite vertices at the centers of the two squares has its other two vertices equally offset from $B$ and $D$: namely, by distance $|AA'|$ and in directions perpendicular to $A'A''$. (Moreover, they're offset by $|CC'|$ in directions perpendicular to $C'C''$.)

In Fensler-Hedwiger, $A'=A''$, so that the new square's vertices are $B$ and $D$ themselves. Not mentioned in OP's statement of FH is that $BD\perp C'C''$; also, the diameter of the square is equal to $|CC'|$, but this fact is obvious:

[image]

There's a bonus square with opposite vertices $A$ and $C$; the remaining vertices are midpoints of $B'D''$ and $B''D'$. This is actually an instance of a deeper theorem: If $P_0P_1\cdots P_n$ and $Q_0Q_1\cdots Q_n$ are *similar* polygonal paths with *opposite* orientations in plane (that is, if they're related by a dilation with a negative scale factor), then the midpoints of $P_iQ_i$ form another similar path.

Other sets of midpoints form parallelograms.

---

- $A_1+A_2 = \frac12(M^2+N^2)$

[image]

Let squares $\square A'B'C'D'$ and $\square A''B''C''D''$ be as shown, and define $x := |X'X''|$. Writing $S'$ and $S''$ for their areas, and $S$ for the area of the square with opposite vertices at their centers, we can find that

$$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 \;=\; 2 \left(\; S' + S'' + 4 S \;\right)$$

For the referenced result from OP's list, we can take $A'=A''$, so that $a=0$. From comments above about the Fensler-Hadwiger theorem, we also have that the diameter of the center square is $\frac12c$. Hence, $S = \frac18 c^2$, and the generalized result specializes back to $b^2+d^2=2(S'+S'')$.